# Unable to set dynamic IP to Azure Virtual machines by terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

Not sure where things are going wrong but I am unable to get the following code working.

**Aim**: To create two (or more) virtual machine with public IP.

**Issue**: Stuck with terraform plan reporting erros as indicated in Error code block.

**Terraform code block is below**:

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "tf-pubip-cluster-aos" {
    count                        = 2
    name                         = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-PUBIP"
    location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
    resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
    allocation_method            = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf-ni-cluster-aos" {
 count               = 2
 name                = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-NI"
 location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
 resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"

ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-IP"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-cluster-aos.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.tf-pubip-cluster-aos.id}"
}
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-cluster-aos" {
  count                 = 2
  name                  = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-cluster-aos.id}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.ax_vm_size}"
```

}

**Error message is below**:

```
Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

    azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos: 2 error(s) occurred:
    azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos[0]: Resource 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pubip-cluster-aos' not found for variable 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pubip-cluster-aos.id'
    azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos[1]: Resource 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pubip-cluster-aos' not found for variable 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pubip-cluster-aos.id'
```

Couldn't figure it out... Any assistance will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create 2 public ips, not one, but you try and reference it like it was a single ip, but its not. its a list. you need to get individual public ip id, something like this:

```
"${element(azurerm_public_ip.tf-pubip-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index)}"
```

Comment: Thank you @4c74356b41 :)


That is my mistake, I have used it before but I don't know what it really does?

May I be allowed to ask, what .*.id,count.index really does?

Comment: takes element number x from the list of id's. you can read the docs about element function

Comment: The * in the expression "resource_name.*.id" is called the "splat" operator.  
It returns a list (array) of all resources created of a specific "resource_name" type  
without requiring to define the list variable in advance.
Then, like any other list, you can access any element in the list using the "element(<LIST>, <INDEX>)" function which receives 2 parameters 1. List 2. Index (Numbered location in list)