# terraform: add public IP to only one azure VM

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure, azure-public-ip

I'm creating 4 vms through count in azurerm_virtual_machine but i want to create only one public IP and associate it with the first VM ? is that possible if so how ?

below is my template file

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
  count               = 4
  name                = ...
  location            = ...
  resource_group_name = ...
  ip_configuration {
    subnet_id                     = ... 
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address = ...
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
  name                = ...
  location            = ...
  resource_group_name = ...
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vms" {
  count                             = 4
  network_interface_ids             = [element(azurerm_network_interface.nics.*.id, count.index)]
}
```

i have already gone through below questions but they are create multiple public ip's & add them to all vms.

[multiple-vms-with-public-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829675/issues-with-creating-multiple-vms-with-terraform-for-azure)

[set-dynamic-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842587/unable-to-set-dynamic-ip-to-azure-virtual-machines-by-terraform)

[attach-public-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319668/unable-to-create-and-attach-a-public-ip-ro-a-vm-by-terraform?rq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Public IPs are created using [azurerm_public_ip](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/public_ip):

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestPublicIp1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}
```

Having the address in your `azurerm_network_interface` you could do the following using [Conditional Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html):

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
  count               = 4
  name                = ...
  location            = ...
  resource_group_name = ...

  ip_configuration {

    subnet_id                     = ... 
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address            = ...
    
    public_ip_address_id = count.index == 1 ? azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id : null
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks i miss placed prefix in question but what i needed was the conditional check thanks this helps :) !

Comment: @ArigatoManga No problem. Glad it helped:-)